# Items jump round on hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Link: http://path.com.my/v2/gallery/

Try when you hover/mouseover one of the links in the tab, especially near EXTERIOR, ILLUMINATED, INTERIOR, PYLON , the items on the second row keep moves around.

I tried changing a few of the CSS on hover but it doesn't seems to work.
Anyone can help?

Comment: can you provide me tab css code on hover and with hover.

Comment: Solved:

margin: 0 6px 0 0 !important;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float` from `.sortLink` and use `inline-block` instead.

Use following css:

```
.sortLink {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, removing float and using in-block helps.
1 more thing appreciate if you can help, if you see the image thumbnail, the border there is overlapping as shown in this image: http://i.imgur.com/X5eCJ7D.jpg
How can we solve this?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight As i see it looks some positioning problem that is coming  from JavaScript calculations. Better post it as another question so that you might get help from someone more experianced

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
margin: 0 6px 0 0 !important;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.1 more thing appreciate if you can help, if you see the image thumbnail, the border there is overlapping as shown in this image: i.imgur.com/X5eCJ7D.jpg How can we solve this?

Comment: oky.. let me see... can you upward my answer.. to help other people..

Comment: change image height and width...

Comment: upvoted, but changing image height and weight didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float:left; from a tag and display:inline-block;

```
.sortLink {
   /* float:left; */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.1 more thing appreciate if you can help, if you see the image thumbnail, the border there is overlapping as shown in this image: i.imgur.com/X5eCJ7D.jpg How can we solve this?

Comment: Welcome. if this answers your first question please up-vote the answer.